# In angular2 I'm using canActivate but when it returns false it still goes to the route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In angular2 I'm using canActivate but when it returns false it still goes to the route.

**Here my code below:**

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        this.isAuthRequired = route.data.isAuthRequired;
        this.isCompanyView = route.data.isCompanyView;

        return this.init();  
  }
```

This code returns true or false depending on the routes data e.g. isAuthRequired etc.

Is this still meant to go to the route? because it does and just shows a blue screen with no console errors which is good but I'm wanting it to redirect to homepage or atleast stay on the previous page.

How is this feature mean't to work and do you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are returning a `boolean` or `promise` or `observar` from the init() method.
Returning true from init() will navigate to the selected routing. 
Returning false will prevent page navigation from the current screen.

something like the below :-

```
init(): boolean{
    /* your application logic */

    return true;
}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    this.isAuthRequired = route.data.isAuthRequired;
    this.isCompanyView = route.data.isCompanyView;

    return this.init();  
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I tried that and true or false hard coded still gives me a blue screen., because its changed route

Comment: When I return false it still navigates to next url route

Comment: Did you try to do a debug output if your can activate method is really called? It must be set on the routes array for the route you want to get.